# Change Legend labels ggplotly2

Tags: r, legend, ggplotly

I am trying to change the legend labels for my graph.

when using `slzsoil_js_plot_march <- ggplot(slz_soil_Js_march, mapping = aes(TIMESTAMP, Js, color = as.factor(Port))) + geom_line() + labs(title = "SLZ La Casita Sensors 1&4") + scale_color_manual(name = "Sensor", values = c("1" = "darkblue", "4" = "red"))` everything is fine. when using `scale_color_manual(name = "Sensor", values = c("2" = "darkblue", "3" = "red"))` the graph goes greyscale.

Comment: Please provide the data and code you are using to create the original plot, as that will make it easier to provide a possible solution.

Comment: @mhovd I just did sorry - also here ```slzsoil_js_plot_march <- ggplot(slz_soil_Js_march, mapping = aes(TIMESTAMP, Js, color = as.factor(Port))) + geom_line() + labs(title = "SLZ La Casita Sensors 1&4") + scale_color_manual(name = "Sensor", values = c("1" = "darkblue", "4" = "red"))```

Comment: Please also add a representative amount of data, e.g. using `dput(slz_soil_Js_march)`. If the output is too large, you can use `dput(head(slz_soil_Js_march, 20))`